# Parse Error: syntax error.... eval()'d code

Tags: pagination

I'm pretty new to ExpressionEngine... I was asked to put pagination in for the following page, and I get the following error:
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENDIF in /mnt/stor12-wc2-dfw1/594049/www.somedomain.com/web/content/system/expressionengine/libraries/Functions.php(656) : eval()'d code on line 181

I don't know how to fix it, and it only appears when I put in the pagination code. Any ideas?

Thanks!

```
{if segment_2 == ""}   
<div id="main">
        <div class="wrap">
            <div id="content">
                <div class="block">
                    <h4>NEWS</h4>
                        <div class="block-content">
                        <ul class="news">
                {exp:channel:entries channel="news" limit="6"  dynamic="off" orderby="date" sort="desc" paginate="bottom"}
                 {paginate}
                        <p id="pagination">Page {current_page} of {total_pages} pages {pagination_links}</p>
                    {/paginate} 
                            <li>
                                <div class="pic">
                                    {if !slideshow}<a href="{url_title_path='news'}"><img src="{image}" alt="{title}" /></a>{/if}
                                </div>
                                <div class="details">
                                    <h5>{title}</h5>
                                    <p>{if "{content:has_excerpt}"}{content:excerpt}{if:else}{content}{/if} 
                                    </p> 
                                    {if video_embed != ""}{video_embed}{/if}
                                    {if slideshow} 
                                    {slideshow limit="10"}<a href="{comment_url_title_auto_path}" style="float:left;">{exp:ce_img:pair src="{url}" max="100" crop="yes"}<img src="{made}" alt="{title}" />{/exp:ce_img:pair}</a>{/slideshow}
                               {/if}
                                    <a href="{comment_url_title_auto_path}" style="clear:all;">Read More...</a>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                {/exp:channel:entries}

                        </ul>
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                    </div>
                               </div>
                                            </div>

                  {if:else}
                {exp:channel:entries channel="news" limit="1"  dynamic="off" orderby="date" url_title="{segment_2}"}  
                <div id="main">
                            <div class="wrap">
                                <div id="content">
                                    {if slideshow}
                                    <h4 class="red">{title}</h4> 
                                        <div class="block-content"> 
                                           {if "{content:has_excerpt}"}{content:extended}{if:else}{content}{/if}    
                                                </div>
                                      <div class="coda-slider-wrapper">
                                            <div class="coda-slider preload" id="coda-slider-1">
                                                                            <div id="coda-nav-left-1" style="float:left;" class="top-arrow-nav"><a href="#" title="Previous">&lt; Previous</a></div><div id="coda-nav-right-1" style="float:right;" class="top-arrow-nav"><a href="#" title="Next" >Next &gt;</a></div>  
                                                {slideshow var_prefix="slide"}
                                                <div class="panel" id="panel{count}">
                                                    <div class="panel-wrapper"> 
                                                        {if slide:caption}<p>{slide:caption}</p>{/if}<a class="xtrig" href="#{if slide:total_files == {count}}1{if:else}{exp:mx_calc expression="{count}+1"}{/if}" rel="coda-slider-1">{exp:ce_img:pair src="{slide:url}" width="715" height="536"}<img src="{made}" alt="{title}" width="{width}" height="{height}"  />{/exp:ce_img:pair}</a>
                                                      </div> 

                                                </div>
                                                {/slideshow}

                                            </div><!-- .coda-slider --> 

                                        </div><!-- .coda-slider-wrapper -->
                                                                        <div id="coda-nav-1" class="coda-nav">
                                        <ul>       
                                        {slideshow}<li class="tab{count}"><a href="#{count}">{exp:ce_img:pair src="{url}" max="100" crop="yes"}<img src="{made}" alt="{title}" />{/exp:ce_img:pair}</a></li>{/slideshow}
                                               </ul> 


                                        </div>

                 </div> 
                                  {if:else}    
                                    <div class="block">
                    <h4>{title}</h4>
                    <div class="block-content">
                        <ul class="news">
                            <li>

                                <div class="pic">
                                    <a href="{comment_url_title_auto_path}"><img src="{image}" alt="{title}" /></a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="details">
                                    <p>{content}</p>
                                    {if video_embed != ""}{video_embed}{/if}

                                </div>
                            </li>
                {/exp:channel:entries}
                 </ul>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                </div>

                </div>

            </div>       {/if}      {/if}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the last line of your code you close with 2 if statements. Remove one.

If you still have issues, comment out blocks of code until error disappears.

Now, if you want some additional suggestions, you would be better off removing the if else wrapping the two channel entries tags. Use 2 if statements = and != for the segment instead, which will mean simple conditionals.

An embed would be better for each channel entry tag.

You may even be able to pass some variables to your embedded template so that you only end up using one channel entries tag, because they look very similar.

Comment: Thanks @dadonbike, this did the trick. The other suggestions you have, and in the other answer are also most likely valid, I just don't have time (client budget!) to sniff around too much. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

It's most likely because you're using a complex conditional withing a complex conditional and because you're code isn't closed properly. For complex conditionals (`if:else`) both conditions are parsed. So, try using two simple conditionals. With simple conditionals, only the true case is parsed. I'd highly recommend using the add-on [Switchee](http://www.devot-ee.com/add-ons/switchee) as well.

```
  <div id="main">
    <div class="wrap">
      <div id="content">
        <div class="block">

          {if segment_2 == ""}
            <h4>NEWS</h4>
            <div class="block-content">
              <ul class="news">
              {exp:channel:entries channel="news" limit="6"  dynamic="off" orderby="date" sort="desc" paginate="bottom"}
                {paginate}
                  <p id="pagination">Page {current_page} of {total_pages} pages {pagination_links}</p>
                {/paginate} 
                ...
              {/exp:channel:entries}
              </ul>
              <div class="clear"></div>
            </div> <!-- end .block-content -->
          {/if}

          {if segment_2 != ""}

            {exp:channel:entries channel="news" limit="1"  dynamic="off" orderby="date" url_title="{segment_2}"}  

            {if slideshow}
            <h4 class="red">{title}</h4> 
            <div class="block-content"> 
              {if "{content:has_excerpt}"}{content:extended}{if:else}{content}{/if}
            </div>
            <div class="coda-slider-wrapper">
              <div class="coda-slider preload" id="coda-slider-1">
                <div id="coda-nav-left-1" style="float:left;" class="top-arrow-nav">
                  <a href="#" title="Previous">&lt; Previous</a>
                </div>
                <div id="coda-nav-right-1" style="float:right;" class="top-arrow-nav">
                  <a href="#" title="Next" >Next &gt;</a>
                </div>  
                {slideshow var_prefix="slide"}
                <div class="panel" id="panel{count}">
                  <div class="panel-wrapper"> 
                    {if slide:caption}<p>{slide:caption}</p>{/if}
                    <a class="xtrig" href="#{if slide:total_files == {count}}1{if:else}{exp:mx_calc expression="{count}+1"}{/if}" rel="coda-slider-1">{exp:ce_img:pair src="{slide:url}" width="715" height="536"}<img src="{made}" alt="{title}" width="{width}" height="{height}"  />{/exp:ce_img:pair}</a>
                  </div>
                </div>
                {/slideshow}
              </div> <!-- .coda-slider -->
            </div><!-- .coda-slider-wrapper -->
            <div id="coda-nav-1" class="coda-nav">
              <ul>
                {slideshow}<li class="tab{count}"><a href="#{count}">{exp:ce_img:pair src="{url}" max="100" crop="yes"}<img src="{made}" alt="{title}" />{/exp:ce_img:pair}</a></li>{/slideshow}
              </ul>
            </div> <!-- end .#coda-nav-1 -->
            {/if} <!-- end if slideshow -->

            {if !slideshow}    
            <h4>{title}</h4>
            <div class="block-content">
              <ul class="news">
                <li>
                  <div class="pic">
                    <a href="{comment_url_title_auto_path}"><img src="{image}" alt="{title}" /></a>
                  </div>
                  <div class="details">
                    <p>{content}</p>
                    {if video_embed != ""}{video_embed}{/if}
                  </div>
                </li>
              </ul>
              <div class="clear"></div>
            </div> <!-- end .block-content -->
            {/if} <!-- end if !slideshow -->

            {exp:channel:entries}

          {/if} <!-- end if segment_2 != "" -->

        </div> <!-- end .block -->
      </div> <!-- end #content -->
    </div> <!-- end .wrap -->
  </div> <!-- end #main -->
```